# Adjusting legend.title ,legend.text and legend color in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am unable to change the color of the Segmentation legend in the plot. I need two different colors for it as a text in the legend and as well as in the visual plot.

```
   er<-  ggmap(sq_map2) + 
   geom_point(data = sisquoc, size = 3,  aes(fill = Segmentation)) +
   geom_line(data = sisquoc, size = 3,  aes(color =SpeedMeterPerSecond)) +
   geom_text(data = sisquoc, aes(label = paste("  ", 
   as.character(Location_ids), sep="")), 
         angle = 60, hjust = 0, color = "sienna4",size = 6 ) 


   gg<- er  +   labs(x ="Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
   theme(axis.title = element_text(size=20), 
     panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",size = 0.5, linetype = 
   "dotted"),
     panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'dotted',colour 
   = "black"), 
     panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'dotted',colour 
   = "black"),
     panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5),
     axis.text.y   = element_text(size=18),
     axis.text.x   = element_text(size=18))

   gg  + theme(legend.position="right", 
         legend.title = element_text(colour="Black", size=18),
         legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 15),
         legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey90",
                                    size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                                    colour ="black"))  + scale_color_continuous(name="Speed (m/s)\n")
```

Comment: The easiest would probably be to add `+scale_color_continuous(name="Speed (m/s)\n")`

Comment: Thank you but i am getting error. + scale_color_continuous(name="Speed (m/s)\n")
Error in +scale_color_continuous(name = "Speed (m/s)\n") : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: hm, strange. Are you sure the error does not occur somewhere else in your code, i.e., does the error occur when you omit `+scale_color_conti...` ?

Comment: Btw, you should change the code/input of your original question based on answers. Otherwise people will not be able to understand the problem the question was supposed to solve

Comment: That was ment to say "you should **not**..." :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work. 
Just specify the legend title explicitly and add `\n` at the end of the string, which adds an extra blank row:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, col=Petal.Length))+ 
  geom_point() + scale_color_continuous(name="my scale\n")
```

Alternatively you could try changing the legend orientation, which 
however usually is most compact when the legend is at the bottom.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, col=Petal.Length))+ 
  geom_point() + theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: @Saara great! I also added 2nd option, which might be helpful

Comment: Do you know how to change the segmentation legend color ?

Comment: But where should i add this ?

Comment: just replace `fill = Segmentation`  by `col = Segmentation` in line 2 of your code

Comment: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale   I am getting this error.

Comment: I see, you cannot have discrete and continuous color scale for same x/y values. Maybe use pch instead? i.e., `pch = Segmentation`?

Comment: It also kind of doesn't make sense to visualize walking/running by points, as you do this throughout segments, probably would make more sense to use `geom_line(aes(col=SpeedMeterPerSecond), lty = Segmentation)`

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)